# best way to compare 2 variables with 4 values each

Tags: javascript

I have 2 variables... both of them can get a status (0,1,2,"xxx")
What would be the best way to compare these variables? Or are a lot of if's and else if's the best way?

```
if((Status1 && Status2) == 2){
    connectorImage = "connector.png";
}
else if((Status1 && Status2) == 1){
    connectorImage = "connector_grey.png";
}
 else if(Status1 == 1 && Status2 == 2){
    connectorImage = "connector_greytogreen.png";
}...
```

Comment: both variable get same values or different?

Comment: Your code is full of errors, give us a clear example of what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far. We can not help you otherwise.

Comment: what exactly is "xxx"? a random int or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
if(Status1 == Status2){
    //Do something    
}else if(Status1 < Status2){
    //Do something else
}else if(Status2 > Status1){
    // Do something else
}
```

This should work, unless if all 16 combinations require a unique action. Then you're stuck with lots of `if's and else's`

Answer (score 1):

it depends on what exactly you need to compare.
e.g.: If you need to get the correct image to a status i would use something like this:

```
function getImageByStatus(int status) {
  switch (status) {
    case 1:
      return "connector.png";
    case 2:
      return "connector_grey.png";
  }
  return "";
}
```

In case you have more complex comparisons, your only way might be some if-statements

Answer (score 0):

1. You can construct connector image from statuses:

var connectorImage = status1 + "_" + status2 + ".png";

and rename you images to something like "0_0.png", "1_0.png", etc.

2. Or rename your status to something more meaningfull
3. Or create a mapping between combined statues and connector names:

   var statusesToConnectorImages = {
       "0_0" : "connector.png",
       "0_1" : "connector_grey.png"
   }
   var connectorImage = statusesToConnectorImages[status1 + "_" + status2];